# docker push to a private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to push an image to a private docker registry. The error that I receive is:

Error: Status 404 trying to push repository : ""

I issued following commands to create and push image:

```
docker tag <your-project-name>/<your-image-name> <docker-registry-machine>/<your-project-name>/<your-image-name>
docker push <docker-registry-machine>/<your-project-name>/<your-image-name>
```

The error received is not informative, looks something is not found. Are there any verbose or debug options for the docker push command or any other way to debug this?

Answer (score -3):

Most possible cause for this is the error/typo in the docker-registry path.

You can try adding --debug to see some more details about the error you are getting.